# How to custom fields by query in command geoNear?

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, nosql

I have a geoNear command:

```
{
"geoNear": "user",
"near": [
  104.4859511,
  10.3804459
],
"spherical": true,
"distanceMultiplier": 6371000,
"minDistance": 0.038378767752844,
"maxDistance": 0.47088369172814,
"num": 6
```

}

I retrieve mongo DB, return some data:

```
"results": [
     {
       "dis": 244511.13644192,
       "obj": {
         "_id": ObjectId("540af074e4b06192b9481436"),
         "user_id": NumberInt(219372),
         "full_name": "Guest_219372",
         "avatar": "",
         "birthday": ISODate("2002-01-05T17:00:00.0Z"),
         "sex": NumberInt(0),
         "feeling": "",
         "voice_intro": "",
         "location": [
           106.684767,
           10.785003 
        ],
         "last_update": NumberInt(0),
         "last_update_location": NumberInt(1410002680) 
      } 
    } 
]
```

I want to limit the data by only a few fields, using "query" with help in mongo official site but it does not return data. I can not check the right and wrong of the query in command geoNear. I have tried to aggregation and found that it supports $ project, geoNear things simpler. I'm using minDistance want your client, do not support aggregation minDistance, forcing me to take command geoNear.

```
{
    "geoNear": "user",
    "near": [
      104.4859511,
      10.3804459
    ],
    "spherical": true,
    "distanceMultiplier": 6371000,
    "minDistance": 0.038378767752844,
    "maxDistance": 0.47088369172814,
    "num": 6,   
    "query": {
        "find": { 
            "user_id": true,
            "_id": false
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: minDistance is supported with aggregation $geoNear, it's just not documented. Try it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Neil Lunn! I will to try with aggregation. But is there a way to handle the query command geoNear not?

Comment: I'm clearly understanding what your expected end result is, mainly because you don't seem to say that. MongoDB 2.6 has $near and $nearSphere which are integrated into the standard query engine. Aggregation $geoNear allows a distance field to be projected.

Comment: I need distance of two location (using 2dsphere type). If I get result by query, mongo will help me to calculating distance, I do not believe in an algorithm of third party...